# In ubuntu 14.04 the theme does not load correctly if autologin is enabled

Tags: 14.04, themes, auto-login

Well, the title describes my problem. If I disable auto login then everything works fine. If I enable it, the theme doesn't show up correctly after booting. If I logout and login again, then it works.

This happens even with the Radiance theme. The window title bars appear dark after booting, however after logout and login the Radiance theme shows up as it should.

Any idea?

Thanks for the help

Comment: name of theme? its version if possible?

Comment: Hi Johnny
This happens even with the Radiance theme.The window title bars appear dark after booting, however after logout and login the Radiance theme shows up as it should.

Comment: Do you happen to have a dual screen? I have a similar problem even without autologin if I login before the second screen resolution is taken into account